# Radio Buttons to go to URL

Tags: html, css, url, radio-button

I'm trying to get the radio buttons to go to the urls below and can't get them to work.  What am I missing?  I've tried everything that I could possibly think of to get the checked radio button to go to a url but I can't figure it out.  Let me know what additional information you need.  Thanks.

```
     <div class="pos_lc">
      <div class="container">
        <!-- OUTER SHADOW -->
        <div class="de">
          <!-- TEXT -->
          <div class="den">
            <!-- LINE -->
            <hr class="line">
            <hr class="line">
            <hr class="line">
            <!-- SWITCH -->
            <div class="switch">

              <!-- TEXT -->
              <label for="switch_off"><span><img class="img_btn" src="/pics/home25w.png" alt="home" height="25px" width="25px"/></span></label>
              <label for="switch_1"><span><img class="img_btn" src="/pics/bio25w.png" alt="bio" height="25px" width="25px"/></span></label>
              <label for="switch_2"><span><img class="img_btn" src="/pics/music25w.png" alt="music" height="25px" width="25px"/></span></label>
              <label for="switch_3"><span><img class="img_btn" src="/pics/calendar25w.png" alt="calendar" height="25px" width="25px"/></span></label>
              <label for="switch_4"><span><img class="img_btn" src="/pics/contact25w.png" alt="contact" height="25px" width="25px"/></span></label>
              <label for="switch_5"><span><img class="img_btn" src="/pics/store25w.png" alt="store" height="25px" width="25px"/></span></label>

              <!-- INPUT -->
              <input id="switch_off" name="radio-set" type="radio">
              <a href="#st-panel-1"></a>
              <input id="switch_1" name="radio-set" type="radio">
              <a href="#st-panel-2"></a>
              <input id="switch_2" name="radio-set" type="radio">
              <a href="#st-panel-3"></a>
              <input id="switch_3" name="radio-set" type="radio">
              <a href="#st-panel-4"></a>
              <input id="switch_4" name="radio-set" type="radio">
              <a href="#st-panel-5"></a>
              <input id="switch_5" name="radio-set" type="radio">
              <a href="#st-panel-6"></a>

              <!-- LIGHT -->

              <div class="light"><span></span></div>
              <!-- DOT -->
              <div class="dot"><span></span></div>
              <!-- CENTER -->
              <div class="dene">
                <div class="denem">
                  <div class="deneme">
                  </div><!-- deneme -->
                </div><!-- denem-->
              </div><!-- dene -->
            </div><!--switch -->
          </div><!-- den -->
        </div><!-- de -->
      </div><!-- container -->          
    </div><!-- pos_lc -->
```

Comment: I could be missing something here, but have you tried placing the radio buttons inside of the `<a>` tags, rather than before?

Comment: I just tested my theory and I guess wrapping the radio button in the anchor tag doesn't work... You might have to use Javascript to check for changes to the radio buttons and then redirect the page.

Answer (score 1):

Using HTML and straight javaScript, you can use the following. I just gathered it from a few random searches on the topic.

```
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">

     function radioLink(dest){

         if (document.radioLinks.pickme)

            if (dest == 'NBC')
                location='http://www.NBCexample.org'
            if (dest == 'CBS')
                location='http://www.CBSexample.org'
            if (dest == 'ABC')
                location='http://www.ABCexample.org'
     }

 </script>
```

...

```
<FORM NAME="radioLinks">
     <INPUT TYPE="radio" NAME="pickme" id="NBC" onClick="radioLink(NBC)"> NBC Networks
     <INPUT TYPE="radio" NAME="pickme" id="NBC" onClick="radioLink(CBS)"> CBS Networks
     <INPUT TYPE="radio" NAME="pickme" id="NBC" onClick="radioLink(ABC)"> ABC Networks
 </FORM>
```

You can obviously build on this and make it more involved, but I am just pointing you in a possible direction to use.

Comment: I'm wondering if there's more behind all this that I'm missing...here is the Codepen which will show everything...
http://codepen.io/btheoret/pen/yxkml

I'd like it to work just like the navigation menu at the bottom of my live site: www.briantheoret.com but it would instead use the rotating knob for navigation.

Comment: Ok, I just looked at your code pen. What about using the onClick commands for the labels you have tied to each section of the knob for images?
'<label for="switch_off" onClick=" radioLink()"><span><img class="img_btn" src="http://www.briantheoret.com/pics/icons/home25w.png" alt="home" height="25px" width="25px"/></span></label>'

In this case, the "radioLink()" function is triggered in the label for switch off with the onClick method.

EDIT: Also, you have some great music!

Comment: I look at your codepen also and I've updated my [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mdesdev/F2RHa/) with your CSS and radio labels, now it work just like navigation menu on the bottom of your site ;)

Answer (score 0):

jQuery solution, here's a [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mdesdev/F2RHa/)

I look at your source code and I noticed that you didn't include jQuery library so first of all you must include jQuery library in your `<head>` section like below

[Download jQuery Library 1.10.2](http://jquery.com/download/) and put the library in your root folder than put below code in the `<head>` section of your HTML document.

```
<script src="jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
```

or use CDN version

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
```

---

Then give `class` to radio element same as the `id` of the section element

```
<input id="switch_off" name="radio-set" type="radio">
<input id="switch_1" class="st-panel-1" name="radio-set" type="radio" checked>
<input id="switch_2" class="st-panel-2" name="radio-set" type="radio">
<input id="switch_3" class="st-panel-3" name="radio-set" type="radio">
<input id="switch_4" class="st-panel-4" name="radio-set" type="radio">
<input id="switch_5" class="st-panel-5" name="radio-set" type="radio">
```

*In your case I can't use HTML5 data attribute (your doctype is XHTML 1.0) but it's the same because we will target section element with class.

---

Then include this script just before the `</body>` tag

```
<script>
$(function() {
  $('input[type="radio"]').click(function() {
    if($(this).is(':checked')) {
       $('html, body').stop().animate({ scrollTop: $('#'+$(this).attr('class')).offset().top }, 1500, 'easeOutQuart');
    }
  });
});
</script>
```